# implementation of a stack in C

Tags: c, stack

Below is my implementation of a stack in `C`. Is it correct? And/or is there anything that I should fix to make it better in any way?

**stack.h**

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#define EMPTY_STACK -1
typedef struct stack
{
  char ch;
  struct stack* prev;
} Stack;

extern Stack* init_stack(void);
extern char pop(Stack*);
extern void push(Stack*, char);

#endif
```

**stack.c**

```
#include "stack.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

Stack* init_stack()
{
  Stack* ret = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
  ret->prev = NULL;
  return ret;
}

char pop (Stack* stck)
{
  char ret;
  if (stck->prev)
  {
    ret = stck->ch;
    Stack* prv = stck->prev;
    stck->prev = prv->prev;
    stck->ch = prv->ch;
    free(prv);
    return ret;
  }
  else
    return EMPTY_STACK;
}

void push (Stack* stck, char ch)
{
  Stack* new_nd = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

  new_nd->prev = stck->prev;
  new_nd->ch = stck->ch;

  stck->prev = new_nd;
  stck->ch = ch;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Too lazy to retype a tailored response, but some of this might be useful: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/dynamic-array-written-in-c/15823#15823

Answer (score 6):

I would advise you not implementing stacks with a linked list because for each `char` of info you consume `2 * sizeof(void*)` because of memory alignment in your struct.

Because of this you won't be able to handle a big amount of data.

What happens if you `push` EMPTY_STACK ? Your pop will return a false EMPTY_STACK when going through the if. Isn't there a better way to handle this ?

Answer (score 3):

Because your init_struct returns a struct that has no data, I think you need to set the data value:

```
ret->ch = EMPTY_STACK;
```

push() should then be modified to see if the char is currently EMPTY_STACK and if so, that should be updated, with no new struct allocated.

```
void push (Stack* stck, char ch)
{
   if ( stck->ch == EMPTY_STACK )
   {
      stck->ch = ch;
      return;
   }
```

pop() should also deal with a struct that has no data:

```
char pop (Stack* stck)
{
  char ret = stck->ch;
  if (stck->prev)
  {
    Stack* prv = stck->prev;
    stck->prev = prv->prev;
    stck->ch = prv->ch;
    free(prv);
  }
  else
     /* set the stack to empty */
     stck->ch = EMPTY_STACK;
  return ret;
}
```

You might want to add a check for a NULL pointer passing in to push() and pop() as well.

I think the easiest way to do a stack is to have a struct that contains a pointer to your data, which gets the output of malloc() from stack_init()  and realloc(), if necessary from push(). You also keep an int in the struct that keeps track of the current size of the stack, and probably the current allocated size.

```
struct stack {
   char *data;
   int items;
   int allocated_size;
}
```

Alternatively, there can be two structs. One for the base of the stack, and another to hold the data of the stack.

```
struct stack_node  {
     char ch;
     struct stack_node* prev;
}

struct stack {
     struct stack_node* top;
     int size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define EMPTY_STACK -1
```

This is weird.  Maybe instead of returning a magic value, your pop function should have a different interface.  For example, maybe your pop function has an output parameter (pointer) which receives the popped value, and returns a boolean indicating whether or not a value was popped.

```
Stack* ret = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
```

You are speaking C with a C++ accent.  You do not need to cast from `void *` to `struct stack*`.  Leave out the cast.

```
Stack* ret = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
ret->prev = NULL;
```

`malloc` can return `NULL`.  In this case the next line will dereference a `NULL` pointer and crash.  You should check for errors, then return some kind of failure status to the caller, which the caller should also react to.

You also have a `init_stack` which does allocations but no corresponding `free_stack` which frees it.

Come to think of it...  Does `init_stack` really need to allocate?  Maybe it should take a caller-allocated buffer.  For example an interface like:

```
struct stack stack;

init_stack(&stack);

push(&stack, 1);    // XXX - there should be a way to check for errors here.
```

This also brings to mind...  Why a vague name like `push`?  C does not have namespaces and this is a name that could clash with others.  Maybe it should be `stack_push`.  Also more consistent with some of your other function names.